# In Symfony2, how do you add a session to an anonymous user

Tags: php, symfony

The following code gets the current user whether they are logged in or not.

```
$token = $this->securityContext->getToken();
$user = $token->getUser();
```

If they are logged in a `User` object is returned, if they are anonymous `String => "anon."` is returned.

To add a session attribute to the user you do the following:

```
$user->setAttribute("monty", "python");
```

But if it's an anonymous user an error is thrown because `$user` is a non-object.

Comment: What do you want? Do you want to know if a user is logged in?

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan I want to use session variables instead of query parameters for SEO reasons. For example, filtering a "Recent Activity" sidebar widget/module. Using the session to store the filter key.

Comment: So you want to set session variables with visitors. For example if a visitor visits a product so you will set other products like the visited one?

Comment: By the way, you can get the current user using just: `$this->getUser();` There is no need to get token first.

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan Yeah, think of the website as a `Product Social Network` and in the sidebar there a `Recently Activity` widget that can be filtered by `All | Comments | Likes | Joins (new members)`. The visitors (anonymous or logged in) can click on the filter. The purpose of the query parameters is for Progressive Enhancement for non-javascript users but query parameters can be bad for SEO so I am hoping to do with sessions. Make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is service registered with key `session`, so in your controller you could do:

```
$this->get('session')->set('monty', 'python');
```